# Variable safety in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, security, android-resources

I'd like to ask you a question. How safe string values are in Android Studio? Can users get access to database and all other passwords just by checking app files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like **res67** said, anyone can decompile your apk and have access to your code and resources. You should use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to obfuscate your code and minimize reverse engineering but keep this in mind:
**Hard-coded strings wont be obfuscated**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can decompile your apk file. Use Proguard and crypto libraries.